# U-Boot hangs while loading kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot

I am working on Freescale board imx50evk. I have built the uboot.bin and uImage using LTIB (linux target image builder). At the U-Boot prompt I enter the `bootm addr` command, and then it hangs after showing the message "Loading Kernel..."

```
> MX50_RDP U-Boot > boot

MMC read: dev # 0, block # 2048, count 6290 partition # 0 ... 
6290 blocks read: OK
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 70800000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-2.6.35.8
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1323688 Bytes =  1.3 MB
   Load Address: a0008000
   Entry Point:  a0008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ...
```

Comment: Verify that you really have RAM at 0xa0008000, which is the kernel "load address".  U-Boot is probably trying to copy the image to that region of memory when it appears to hang.

Comment: then how to change the load address of kernel??? to 70800000

Comment: there are utilities such as mkImage, by which you can relocate the address

Comment: Something like: `mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x70800000 -e 0x70800000 -n "2.6.35.8-imx5" -d arch/arm/boot/zImage ../../uImage`

Comment: Please provide us with your u-boot environment (you can do that in u-boot shell, with `env print` command). It can help to debug your problem.

Comment: Can you comment what was the issue if you remember? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that your board really has RAM at 0xa0008000, which is the kernel "load address". U-Boot is probably trying to copy the image to that region of memory when it appears to hang.

[*By your comment, I'll assume that you have verified that main memory does not exist at physical address 0xAXXXXXXX.*]

The uImage file that you are using was made from the zImage file using the `mkimage` utility.

You probably have to manually edit the line that looks like

```
zreladdr-y     := 0xa0008000
```

in `arch/arm/mach-XXX/Makefile.boot` for your board.  The convention is that this address should be the base of physical RAM plus an offset of 0x8000 (32K).  Then adjust the other values in the file.  Delete the `zImage` file and perform another *make* for the kernel.

Comment: ya i have changed the load address of kernel image using mkimage and it works fine on loading kernel, but now it hangs out at Starting kernel ... and never returns to prompt...

Comment: @ASB - Not much has to happen after the *"Starting kernel ..."* before the *"Uncompressing Linux..."* is displayed when the U-Boot wrapper coder is executed.  Maybe you need to use an **in-circuit emulator** (i.e. J-Link) to investigate what is going wrong.  Isn't this an evaluation board? Isn't there a demo kernel with source code to use as an example?  Why are you encountering gross errors like incorrect load addresses?  Have you configured your build scripts properly for your board?

Comment: Verify the machine ID that U-Boot passes to the kernel.  If it's incorrect or unrecognized, then that can cause the decompression program to hang on some Freescale SoCs.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378563/how-do-i-find-arm-linux-entry-point-when-it-fails-to-uncompress/18392238#18392238

Comment: Enable **earlyprintk** in kernel (via `CONFIG_EARLYPRINTK` option and some other options like UART number, just check it in `menuconfig`, they are all in the same group). And also pass `earlyprintk` param to kernel from u-boot via `bootargs` environment variable. This way you will be able to see where kernel stuck.

Answer (score 0):

While building 3.20 development kernels for rockchip's rk3288 I found using LZO image compression made the device hang at 'Starting the kernel.'  I assume it's because of a version miss-match between the build hosts LZO and the deployed decompression code, so it could probably happen with any of the compression algorithms.  In my case switch to gzip fixed it.

This is only my assumption for why changing the compression algorithm gave a bootable kernel. Please correct me if I'm wrong.