# How do I find ARM Linux entry point when it fails to uncompress?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, boot, u-boot

I am trying to boot Linux via U-boot on a custom board with i.MX6 (CPU core is ARM Cortex A9)

We seem to have ported Das U-Boot(2009.08) successfully. But booting Linux fails at the last U-Boot message: "Starting kernel ..."

Here is my relevant environment:

```
bootargs=console=ttymxc1,115200 vmalloc=400M root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootwait consoleblank=0 earlyprintk video=mxcfb0:dev=lcd,LCD-ORTUS,if=RGB24 video=mxcfb1:dev=hdmi,1280x720M@60,if=RGB24 calibration tsdev=tsc2004 fbmem=10M,28M
bootcmd=ext2load mmc 0:1 10800000 /boot/uImage ; bootm 10800000
```

The boot output is

```
Loading file "/boot/uImage" from mmc device 0:1 (xxa1)  
4043552 bytes read  
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 10800000 ...  
   Image Name:   Linux-3.0.35  
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)  
   Data Size:    4043488 Bytes =  3.9 MB  
   Load Address: 10008000  
   Entry Point:  10008000  
   Verifying Checksum ... OK  
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK  
OK  

Starting kernel ...
```

When I objdump the kernel, at address 80008000, I see the entry point at arch/arm/kernel/head.S, and not arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S

What I see is, the kernel does not even decompress. I tried adding some register manipulation code to signal GPIOs in compressed/head.S with no response.

My question is, how can I make sure U-Boot is calling the correct entry point?

The exact same kernel binary successfully boots on Freescale's reference board, using the same U-Boot commands.

EDIT: I added some traces to U-Boot. Just before calling the kernel, the pointer theKernel is 10008000 and not 10800000. Does this mean U-boot is jumping at the wrong location?

Comment: Do you have JTAG? If so, just debug it.

Comment: I think Kernel will start only after decompression, after starting kernel print, kernel will jump to the kernel entry function which u-boot gets from the kernel image header. You copied compressed kernel from boot media to 10800000, bootm command will uncompress and put the kernel on the correct load address which is 10008000, 32K boundary from RAM start address. If it is not booting, then most probably the reason is machine id. I would like to know what was the correct reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> We seem to have ported Das U-Boot successfully.

There's evidence that that is a faulty assumption.

> Just before calling the kernel, the pointer theKernel is 10008000 and not 10800000.

Which version of U-Boot are you using?
In both 2012.10 and 2013.04 versions of U-Boot, the variable `theKernel` is only declared and used by code for arches like AVR32 and MIPS.
There is no ARM code that should be using `theKernel`.

```
u-boot-2012.10$ find . -print | xargs grep theKernel
./arch/avr32/lib/bootm.c:   void    (*theKernel)(int magic, void *tagtable);
./arch/avr32/lib/bootm.c:   theKernel = (void *)images->ep;
./arch/avr32/lib/bootm.c:          theKernel, params_start);
./arch/avr32/lib/bootm.c:   theKernel(ATAG_MAGIC, params_start);
./arch/microblaze/lib/bootm.c:  void    (*theKernel) (char *, ulong, ulong);
./arch/microblaze/lib/bootm.c:  theKernel = (void (*)(char *, ulong,    ulong))images->ep;
./arch/microblaze/lib/bootm.c:      (ulong) theKernel, rd_data_start, (ulong) of_flat_tree);
./arch/microblaze/lib/bootm.c:  theKernel (commandline, rd_data_start, (ulong) of_flat_tree);
./arch/mips/lib/bootm.c:    void (*theKernel) (int, char **, char **, int *);
./arch/mips/lib/bootm.c:    theKernel = (void (*)(int, char **, char **, int *))images->ep;
./arch/mips/lib/bootm.c:        (ulong) theKernel);
./arch/mips/lib/bootm.c:    theKernel(linux_argc, linux_argv, linux_env, 0);
./arch/mips/lib/bootm_qemu_mips.c:  void (*theKernel) (int, char **, char **, int *);
./arch/mips/lib/bootm_qemu_mips.c:  theKernel = (void (*)(int, char **, char **, int *))images->ep;
./arch/mips/lib/bootm_qemu_mips.c:      (ulong) theKernel);
./arch/mips/lib/bootm_qemu_mips.c:  theKernel(0, NULL, NULL, 0);
./arch/nds32/lib/bootm.c:   void    (*theKernel)(int zero, int arch, uint params);
./arch/nds32/lib/bootm.c:   theKernel = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;
./arch/nds32/lib/bootm.c:          (ulong)theKernel);
./arch/nds32/lib/bootm.c:   theKernel(0, machid, bd->bi_boot_params);
u-boot-2012.10$
```

<s>**Please explain how you are able to trace a variable that should not be defined or assigned on an ARM processor.**</s>

The next output after U-Boot prints "Starting kernel ..." should be "Uncompressing Linux...".
For the Freescale arch this text output is dependent on the proper passing of the `machine type number` (aka `arch_id`) by U-Boot to the kernel.
You need to verify that this `machine type number` is properly defined in U-Boot.

What does your configuration file for U-Boot look like?

> I tried adding some register manipulation code to signal GPIOs in compressed/head.S with no response.

Did you sanity check this code to ensure that it works as you expect?
Did you try out the GPIO operations from the U-Boot command line?

> My question is, how can I make sure U-Boot is calling the correct entry point?

For the ARM arch, it is a jump to the address specified in the **bootm** command.
Since the uImage load address and the **bootm** specify the same 0x10800000 address, that should be good (assuming that U-Boot is correctly configured and built for ARM).

> Just before calling the kernel, the pointer theKernel is 10008000 and not 10800000. Does this mean U-boot is jumping at the wrong location?

<s>**YES.**

If you check the source code (for AVR32 or MIPS), you'd find that `theKernel` is assigned from the image header, specifically the entry point value.  U-Boot would then jump to this location.

But the real problem is that your ARM Cortex A9 should not be using this code or this variable.</s>
It seems as if that U-Boot is not configured for the proper arch and/or the machine type may not be correctly defined.

**CORRECTIONS**:

As the OP pointed out, older versions of U-Boot did use the variable `theKernel` even for the ARM arch.

The line of U-Boot output:

```
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
```

indicates that U-Boot has (successfully) copied the kernel image (without the image information header) from the `bootm` address of 0x10800000 (plus offset 0x40 for the header length) to the load address of 0x10008000.  This memory move operation is performed by the procedure `bootm_load_os()` in **common/cmd_bootm.c**.

So the value of 0x10008000 that you reported is correct for `theKernel`.
There is no indication that U-Boot is jumping to the wrong location.

As already mentioned, you should verify that the machine type is correctly defined.  The value would be used in `__arch_decomp_setup()` in [arch/arm/plat-mxc/include/mach/uncompress.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/plat-mxc/include/mach/uncompress.h?v=3.0;a=arm#L24)  so that text could be output during the decompression prior to the kernel booting.

Comment: Thenk you for the detailed explanation. I will also edit my question because we are using U-Boot 2009.08, which is the officially supported version by Freescale. There, **theKernel** is used in a sub-tree called lib\_arm. Also, we use the Cortex A8 arch to boot A9, which seems prefectly fine for other mx6 based boards.

Comment: Your amendment solved the problem! I did not know I had to add my custom board definitions to mach/uncompress.h

Comment: @Atilla Filiz It would be nice if you added the arch_id  and machine type you used to get things to work.

Comment: @CaptainBli - The actual value of the machine type passed from U-Boot to the kernel is not as important as ensuring that it is recognized.  The OP apparently created a new machine type for his custom board, but missed one source file that required editing. HINT: `grep` your entire source tree (kernel and bootloaders) for the original board's machine type to find code that needs updating.

Comment: @sawdust could you please also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461633/linux-compilation-invalid-entrypoint)

Answer (score 4):

You don't seem to be booting the vmlinux kernel file so you don't have to worry about entry points. The decompression code at the beginning of the image will relocate the kernel as required and jump to the correct entry point when its done. You just have to jump the beginning of the image which uBoot seems to be doing correctly.

I'd turn on kernel debugging, especially the earlyprintk and lowlevel debugging options and try booting again. At least you get to see where it stuffs up.

Edit: As pointed out, my answer only applies if uBoot is doing it's thing correctly in the first place. In this case, there is a possibility that it isn't. Maybe you could create and attempt to boot a dummy 'kernel' which simply switches on some LEDs or outputs some register values to serial (r0, r1 and r2 in particular). Then you can at least check and/or rule out uBoot as the culprit.

Comment: *"uBoot seems to be doing correctly."*  -- There is zero evidence to support that conclusion.  *"I'd turn on kernel debugging"*  -- the OP clearly states that there is no indication that the kernel has uncompressed.  Since the kernel has not started booting, you cannot expect to obtain anything from "kernel debugging" features.  You are only offering generic advice that is not helpful to this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the file that U-Boot is loading is actually the binary image of `vmlinux` file instead the self-extracting `zImage`/`bzImage`? It's just a guess, I'm not an expert on this.

This question I recently asked on Unix Stack Exchange could be of interest for you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197225/is-vmlinuz-and-bzimage-really-the-same