# Enable CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK and CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL in configuration

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, u-boot

I enabled CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK and CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL in my [TI Sitara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitara_ARM_Processor) board configuration file. While building the uImage the following error comes. Why is it coming?

I tried to find out, but I am not able to figure it out properly.

```
....
  CC      arch/arm/kernel/io.o
  AS      arch/arm/kernel/debug.o
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S: Assembler messages:
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `sub ,r1,r2'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr r2,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr ,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: shift expression expected -- `add r1,r1,'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:157: Error: shift expression expected -- `add r2,r2,'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `sub ,r1,r2'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr r2,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#0]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#4]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `str r1,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: ARM register expected -- `ldr ,[,#8]'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: shift expression expected -- `add r1,r1,'
arch/arm/kernel/debug.S:173: Error: shift expression expected -- `add r2,r2,'
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/kernel/debug.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/kernel] Error 2
```

Comment: Does it build fine without CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL ?

Comment: @Mali yeap,it is building fine without CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL

Comment: Which kernel version is this? check the related file in kernel for lines 157, 173. It looks like it is a macro expansion and you are probably missing some defines due to missing config settings?

Comment: See: [Linux entry point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378563/how-do-i-find-arm-linux-entry-point-when-it-fails-to-uncompress).  There are defines that are per *machine/uart*.  As per Auselen, supply the Linux version and your machine directory. `linux-stable/arch/arm$ git grep -i Sitara` returns nothing.

Comment: Typically this is in [debug.S printascii()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/debug.S?id=refs/tags/v3.12#n80), with the macros *waituart*, *senduart* and *busyuart*.

Answer (score 0):

Recent mainline kernel versions for the Sitara processor expect the user to specify the DEBUG_LL UART via the kernel configuration. The options for the different board and processor variants show up when you enable EARLY_PRINTK.

The right UART port should also be selected.