# bootm without device tree blob

Tags: linux, kernel, u-boot, device-tree

The following is an excerpt from the U-Boot help for **bootm** command:

```
bootm [addr [arg ...]]

- boot application image stored in memory
    passing arguments 'arg ...'; when booting a Linux kernel,
    'arg' can be the address of an initrd image
    When booting a Linux kernel which requires a flat device-tree
    a third argument is required which is the address of the
    device-tree blob. To boot that kernel without an initrd image,
    use a '-' for the second argument. If you do not pass a third
    a bd_info struct will be passed instead
```

As I can see in the above `bootm [addr]` should work fine, `arg` is optional.
So something like `bootm 0x1000000` should work.
I **tftp** the linux kernel uImage to 0x1000000, and then want to use the above command.
Is it not possible?

It works fine when i use `bootm 0x1000000 - 0x3000000`, where third argument is address of dtb.
But when i try to boot without dtb, it stops at 
*"Uncompressing kernel image"*

Comment: While your description seems clear enough, the actual console text would be better (just in case you overlooked something).  You should also provide more information, such as kernel version and SoC.  Some SoCs are dependent on data from U-Boot to uncompress that others are not, such as [Freescale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378563/how-do-i-find-arm-linux-entry-point-when-it-fails-to-uncompress/18392238#18392238).  Although the dozen or so instances I've seen of this problem were typically related to an incorrect load address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel that you are using might support only a device tree blob (dtb) based bootup. You would have to make sure that the kernel configurations are set to support legacy boot. It is essential to make sure that your u-boot supports legacy boot too. Like sawdust mentioned, it is always helpful to give SoC, kernel, u-boot info.

Comment: "The kernel that you are using might support only a device tree blob (dtb) based bootup" is true for my case for the kernel have been configured so by menuconfig. I actually took over the project from the middle and was not aware that kernel is configured so, rather that there is such a menuconfig option available  !! Thanks.

Comment: can you please tell the kernel configuration to support legacy boot in a newer kernel?? say 3.10